# How do I hide rows in jQuery based on a particular condition?

Tags: jquery

I would like to filter out/hide rows that may not be relevant.

All the rows have the class of "dataRow"

Each row contains 6 columns. The first column contains a label and the next 5 columns all contain values.

If all the values in a particular row (other than the label in Column 1) contains a 0 then I would like to hide the row.

What would be a good approach to accomplish this in jQuery?

Comment: Please rephrase your question to avoid editorial conflicts. Asking for a "best way" it is always rather subjective and usually too broad

Comment: I've tried doing a whole bunch of things client side in a language called Visual Force which does not have nuanced capability to render a row based on particular conditions utilizing the particular tag.

So I'm hoping that a jQuery guru might have an elegant way to handle this client side. If not I can modify the server side code (APEX) however if this is something that can be accomplished in a few lines of jQuery that might be the better way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try computing the `sum` over each row and then hide it accordingly.

```
$("tr.dataRow").each(function(){
  var hide = false;
  $("td:gt(0)", this).each(function(){
    if(+$(this).text()){
      hide = true;
    }
  });
  $(this).toggle(hide);
});
```

It would be nice to know if all target `td` elements are children of `tr.dataRow`, then  `.children()` could be used.

---

If the above script, here there is a variant using `parseFloat` instead. Although, both codes should work.

```
$(function () {
  $("tr.dataRow").each(function () {
    var hide = false;
    $("td:gt(0)", this).each(function () {
      if (parseFloat($(this).text()) > 0) {
        hide = true;
      }
    });
    $(this).toggle(hide);
  });
});
```

Comment: This won't work as expected. `.text()` returns a string so the result of `0 + "0"` would be `"00"`. (Also this would hide rows with e.g. `-1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1` but that depends on the possible values of the cells)

Comment: @Andreas, I agree, it's better to not believe all are non-negative numbers. My bad. Updated

Comment: I used the code copied and pasted it inside of my $(document).ready(function() and everything worked well! Though Andreas is correct in that the scope of my question was short sighted. It is possible I could have positive and negative values that even out. I can probably modify the code to add a flag. Thanks Alexander.

Comment: ok nevermind Alexander does it again in the time it takes me to post a comment. Thank You!

Comment: Works great in FF, for some reason not in Chrome. This is an internal web application so I can force them to use FF if need be.

Comment: @JosephU., weird. I'm a Chromium user. Anyways, I updated the question with an explicit notation which should work also. If the problem persists, please create a fiddle reproducing the problem :)